# Speed up QSortFilterProxyModel filtering when dealing with nearly large data sets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

Before, i asked [`a question`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#contains-6) about multiple column filtering that we need to represent rows that fit more than one filter pattern.

Now when dealing with big tables (by `big` i mean about 200,000 rows and 4 columns) filtering get slow if we have a table that big (normally this is worst for the first 2 char of filter pattern).

So what is your suggestion on this?

Note : i have my own high performance source data model (instead of `QStandardItemModel`) based on [`this`](https://github.com/antis81/QtModelViewDemo) example witch feed my view for that number of rows in about 1 sec

## Edit 1

Changing my method from this :

```
bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const {
if (/* filtering is enable*/) {
    bool _res = sourceModel()->data(sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent)).toString().contains( /*RegExp for column 0*/);
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount(); col++) {
        _res &= sourceModel()->data(sourceModel()->index(source_row, col + 1, source_parent)).toString().contains(/*RegExp for column col + 1*/);
    }
    return _res;
}
return true;
```

}

To this :

```
bool DataFilter::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const {
    if (_enable) {
        return (sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent.child(source_row, 0)).data().toString().contains( /*string for column 0*/ ))
            && sourceModel()->index(source_row, 1, source_parent.child(source_row, 1)).data().toString().contains(/*string for column 1*/))
            && sourceModel()->index(source_row, 2, source_parent.child(source_row, 2)).data().toString().contains(/*string for column 2*/))
            && sourceModel()->index(source_row, 3, source_parent.child(source_row, 3)).data().toString().contains(/*string for column 3*/));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Look works Perfect.Now filtering work like a charm without delay

Comment: 1. Profile your model performance. 2. Don't use regexps for filtering, write your own methods. 3. If you really need big data support - look at in-memory SQLite as a source for model and filtering.

Comment: You could ditch QSortFilterProxyModel and replace it with your own purpose-built implementation; since you know your app's particular needs, you might be able to design your implementation to be more efficient than QSortFilterProxyModel which has to be general-purpose and can't make any assumptions about the behavior of the code it is interacting with.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner.So you say we should forget `QSortFilterProxyModel`.would it be good idea to implement filtering inside the source data model (derived from `QAbstractTableModel`) if we only need filtering ? if not i'll listen to your recommendation.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov.If i'm right you confirm : Using strings in place of RegExp and in own methods (setters) we set the filter string ?.actually i have no problem with fetching data from MSSQL into my model and as i said it's very fast for 200,000 rows and when we using filtering, the data (that view uses it) is in memory

Comment: When using `&&`, try to help it fail fast - put the least-likely case first.  This will reduce the number of times the subsequent branches of the conjunction must be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of items is very high that you can't load them in one shot, you can try adding items in batches only when they are needed in the view. This can be done by overriding [`canFetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) and [`fetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore). Have a look at the [Fetch More Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html). Note that this is how `QSqlQueryModel` internally loads large models from databases, see [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/models/qsqlquerymodel.cpp#n190).

Here is how your model can be implemented using this approach:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel{
public:
    explicit MyTableModel(int rowCount, QObject* parent=nullptr)
        :QAbstractTableModel(parent),currentRowCount(0),wholeRowCount(rowCount){}
    ~MyTableModel(){}

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override{
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return currentRowCount;
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override{
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return 2;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override{
        Q_ASSERT(index.row()<currentRowCount);
        QVariant val;
        if(role== Qt::DisplayRole || role== Qt::EditRole){
            switch(index.column()){
            case 0:
                val= QString("#%1").arg(index.row()+1, 8, 10, QChar('0'));
                break;
            case 1:
                val= rows[index.row()];
                break;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    bool canFetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) const override{
        if(parent.isValid()) return false;
        return (currentRowCount < wholeRowCount);
    }

    void fetchMore(const QModelIndex& /* index */) override{
        int toFetch= qMin(52, wholeRowCount-currentRowCount);
        char ch = 'A';
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), currentRowCount, currentRowCount+toFetch-1);
        for(int i=0; i<toFetch; i++){
            rows+= QString(QChar(ch));
            if(ch == 'Z') ch = 'A';
            else ch++;
        }
        currentRowCount+= toFetch;
        endInsertRows();
    }

private:
    int currentRowCount;
    int wholeRowCount;
    QStringList rows;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout layout(&w);
    QLineEdit filterLineEdit;
    QTableView tableView;
    layout.addWidget(&filterLineEdit);
    layout.addWidget(&tableView);

    MyTableModel model(200000);
    QSortFilterProxyModel proxyModel;
    proxyModel.setSourceModel(&model);
    proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(-1);
    tableView.setModel(&proxyModel);

    QObject::connect(&filterLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](){
        proxyModel.setFilterFixedString(filterLineEdit.text());
    });

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If you are sure your real bottleneck is filtering, you may also want to avoid using regular expressions as noted by @DmitrySazonov, subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel`, override [`filterAcceptsRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) and provide your algorithm there instead of using the general `QRegExp`-based filters.

Another thing to consider is avoiding to check already-filtered rows when the filter has become narrower, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39414607/2666212).

Comment: I appreciate your answer.but i'm pretty sure that my model works well, i implemented that with a fast internal structure and i can load 200k rows just in a sec (in `release` config).and in this duration i show a progressbar without need of paging .my problem now is real-time filtering with `QSortFilterProxyModel`.could you please explain a little about `algorithm instead of QRegExp-based filter` is that more than comparing strings?

Comment: How do you show a progress bar in this duration? If your model is being loaded in the main thread, the progress bar can not be updated until control is returned to the event loop (when loading has finished). I think you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @IMAN4K , I mean providing a custom implementation for `filterAcceptsRow()` that does not depend on regular expressions (instead it works better because of your specific kind of filtering). However, I really think regular expressions in Qt are very well optimized, and you shouldn't go this way unless you are sure your filtering has very specific needs that are different from normal string/regexp matching.

Comment: @Mike.Using a thread : i will run my query in worker object and also filling my structure and after ending i will emit success signal (in this process the view is hidden and custom progressbar is shown) when success signal is emitted i will give my structure to model and then call `view::show()`.all this happen in about just 1 sec without blocking main loop.

Comment: @IMAN4K , in the github repository you linked, I couldn't find any use of threading, that's why I asked my question. So, are you looking for a way to do filtering in another thread for example? If so, you may want to ask a new question about that specifically, and provide what you've tried. . .

Comment: @No using thread for filtering is not what i want user should see result immediately .could you please look at my edit.this now works well.do you recommend that way ?

Comment: @IMAN4K , if you really see significant difference, it is okay.

Comment: fetch more can not work well with filter . When filtered ,it will only filter the loaded rows.

Comment: @xiaoyifang, You are right. `QSortFilterProxyModel` does not play well with lazily loaded models. This has apparently been [discussed](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-interest-old/2011-January/030641.html) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21349450) [times](https://gist.github.com/micjabbour/6691cdd56c9828ee59fea7352721f119) and I am not sure if there is an easy way to patch `QSortFilterProxyModel`.